Which gradle and kotlin version perfect match for flutter 3.24.1?
I want to update my flutter app to last version but I get many issue on gradle build with kotlin something like
   Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Storage for [D:\project\me\app\dudu-app\build\device_info_plus\kotlin\compileDebugKotlin\cacheable\caches-jvm\jvm\kotlin\source-to-classes.tab] is already registered     
                at org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.util.io.FilePageCache.registerPagedFileStorage(FilePageCache.java:410)


And a lot of more,
that's the stable version to used

3.24.2 just dropped on stable

oh, i just see, oaky let's me try

i am using AGP 8.4.0 with gradle 8.6 and kotlin 1.9.10 , so far so good
